# numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U38')

Tags: python

eu estou começando em python e para meu primeiro 'grande projeto' decidi criar um programa que criptografa, com dupla chave, uma mensagem de acordo com os indexs dos caracteres em uma lista de caracteres ascii.
mas quando estou tentando somar as matrizes que representam cada chave está dando o seguinte erro:

numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U38'), dtype('<U38')) -> dtype('<U38')

já tentei somar as matrizes com '+' tambem e não deu certo

```
import numpy as np
print('-=' * 20)
print('             Encriptador')
print('-=' * 20)

# definindo matriz que vai gerar a chave pública
a = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=(5, 5))

chave_publica = []

alfabeto = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
            'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
            ' ', '!', '"', '#', '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',',
            '-', '.', '/', ':', ';', '<', '=', '>', '?', '@', '[', '/', ']',
            '^', '_', '`', '{', '|', '}', '~',  'á', 'à', 'ã', 'é', 'è', 'í',
            'ì', 'ó', 'ò', 'ú', 'ù', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']


# definindo a chave pública
for k in range(0, 5):
    k = a[k, k]
    chave_publica.append(k)
chave_publica = np.array(chave_publica)

print(f''
      f'chave pública >>>>> {chave_publica}')

chave_privada = []

print('(frase deve ter mais que 5 caracteres)')

msg = (str(input('frase: ')).strip()).lower()


# a chave privada vai depender do tamanho da mensagem
for k in range(0, len(msg)):
    for j in range(0, len(msg[k])):
        letra = alfabeto.index(msg[k][j])
        chave_privada.append(letra)
chave_privada = '[' + (str(chave_privada).strip('[')).strip(']').replace(',', '') + ']'
chave_privada = np.array(chave_privada)
print(f'chave privada >>>>> {chave_privada}')

l_chave_pub = len(str(chave_publica))
l_chave_priv = len(str(chave_privada))


# definindo a chave para criptografada
if l_chave_priv > l_chave_pub:
    n = l_chave_priv // l_chave_pub
    r = l_chave_priv % l_chave_pub
    n_chave_pub = np.repeat(chave_publica, (n-1)) + ([0] * r)
    c_def = np.add(chave_privada, n_chave_pub)
    print(c_def)
else:
    n = l_chave_pub // l_chave_priv
    r = l_chave_pub % l_chave_priv
    n_chave_priv = np.repeat(chave_privada, n) + ([0] * r)
    c_def = np.add(n_chave_priv, chave_publica)

print(c_def)
```

Comment: Não rodei seu código aqui, mas tenho certeza que o problema está nos caracteres especiais. Tipo á, ã, é, í... Você está usando `str()` que irá tratar strings como `ascii`. Sugiro **OU** não usar os caracteres acentuados (prefiro assim), **OU** usar `u'Sua string acentuada'. Ao invés de inicializar a msg com input tente apenas `msg = u'Mensagem é acentuada'`

Comment: Parece que vc também pode mudar o tipo do array. Veja [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037824/how-to-convert-numpy-object-array-into-str-unicode-array) post

Comment: Entendi, vou ajeitar isso e ver se funciona. Obrigado!